# Need help understanding better RNG

Tags: c++, random

In the last example of this post (http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/cpp/threads/1769/c-random-numbers), the author claims that it is a better method for producing random numbers. However, I read this line and am still confused as to what is trying to do.

```
random_integer = lowest+int(range*rand()/(RAND_MAX + 1.0));
```

I tested this code but it kept producing the value of "1" every single time.

I hope someone can provide clarification.

Comment: I guess you should share your definitions of `lowest` and `range` as they're the most likely to blame.

Comment: Hint: since C++11, there is also [uniform_int_distribution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), which is now considered the preferred way of generating random integer numbers within a certain interval.

Answer (score 1):

Say you want to generate random integer in the range `[a, b)`. This can be accomplished by generating random integer in the range `[0, b - a)` and adding `a`:

```
random_integer = a + rand(0, b - a)
```

We can generate random integers in the range `[0, RAND_MAX]` using the ordinary `rand()`. Now, we need to scale this interval to fit `[0, r)`, `r = b - a`. Since `RAND_MAX` is the maximal value returned by `rand()`, `rand() / (MAX_RAND + 1.0)` is in `[0, 1)`. So, `r * rand() / (MAX_RAND + 1.0)` is in `[0, r)`.